# Make DragEventArgs e.X and e.Y relative to Form or Picturebox - NOT the screen

Tags: c#, location, mouse

In a method that gets called by the DragDrop event handler (so i pass it DragEventArgs - which i use to get mouse.X and mouse.Y) it is basing it's e.Location relative to the computer screen. This is not working out for my app. I have other similar methods, and the e.X and e.Y is relative to my Picturebox, which is preferable. Even relative to the form would be okay. Why is this relative to the screen when the others were relative to the picturebox? Here is the method:

```
 public void setMinotaur(DragEventArgs e, List<Cell> cells)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; i++)
            {
                int[] mapData = myMapController.getMapData(i, cells);
                int column = mapData[0];
                int row = mapData[1];
                int right = mapData[2];
                int bottom = mapData[3];



              //  int column = myMap.boardXPos + myMap.myCells[i].myColumn * myMap.myCellSize;
              //  int row = myMap.boardYPos + myMap.myCells[i].myRow * myMap.myCellSize;


                int pbxLocationX = myMapController.myMap.myForm.pbxMap.Location.X;
                int pbxLocationY = myMapController.myMap.myForm.pbxMap.Location.Y;
                int pnlLocationX = myMapController.myMap.myForm.panel2.Location.X;
                int pnlLocationY = myMapController.myMap.myForm.panel2.Location.Y;
                int offsetX = pbxLocationX + pnlLocationX;
                myMapController.myMap.myForm.label1.Text = offsetX.ToString();
                myMapController.myMap.myForm.label2.Text = e.X.ToString();
                int offsetY = pbxLocationY + pnlLocationY;

                if (e.X > column + offsetX &&
                    e.X < column + myMapController.myMap.myCellSize + offsetX)
                {
                    myMapController.myMap.myCells[i].hasMinotaur = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    myMapController.myMap.myCells[i].hasMinotaur = false;
                }
                myMapController.myMap.myForm.label2.Text = e.X.ToString();
            }
        }
```

It is called here:

```
private void pbxMap_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    myDetectMouse.setMinotaur(e, myMap.myCells);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use point to client:

```
PointToClient(new Point(x,y));
```

Here is an example:

```
Point RelativeMouseLoc = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```

Comment: Adding the picturebox before PointToClient in your example? pbx.PointToClient?

Comment: I'm not sure, since i don't really know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: PointToClient just converts a screen `Point` into a relative `Point`

Comment: Thanks. Works nicely.